# An error occurred uploading to the iTunes Store

Tags: ios, xcode4, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-store

We Really need some help on this one:

We've Struggled with all the Apple Mumbo-Jumbo for the Last two months and can't seem to get our APP on the APPStore...

Right now my problem is after Validating the ARCHIVE compilation and sharing it.. in the Submit Process I Get -

"An error occurred uploading to the iTunes Store"

I Really don't Know what I'm doing wrong and don't seem to find ANYTHING on the Internet that solves the problem...

I've been stugling with this for over a week now... I've tried:

- Creating a new Distribution Profile for Code Signing.
- Checking All the Target Settings over and over.
- Changing the FTP mode from Passive to non-Passive
- Connecting from different networks
- Reinstalling Xcode4
- some other Work Arounds like Downloading the application Loader (Haven't installed it yet, but  I Don't Know if I Should)

Please help us, what do you think could be the problem?

Thanks

Hernan

Comment: If nothing else, the Application Loader sometimes gives better error messages, so you may as well try that.  I take it the Validate button completes successfully?

Comment: Why is sharing involved here? Have you tried it with a different connection?

Comment: sounds like you have two accounts, one for asking question, another for answering ?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

If you are unable to upload Apps to Apple and installed the JavaOSX update (April 3, 2012) this may help you regain your ability to upload Apps:

You can work around this issue by re-creating the old Java 1.5 symlinks:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0
```

---

### Edit Oct 5, 2012 Oracle's Java 7

Elaborating on Hackmonford's comment below.

This exact error message also occurs with Oracle's Java SE 7 1.7.0_10 package installed. To resolve, open "Java Preferences" and either change the order to have Apple's Java SE 6 first, or untick Oracle's Java 7 while submitting to the app store. Verify your change by opening the Terminal:

```
prince$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_35"
```

Comment: Thank you Nigel! I tried everything and this was the only thing that helped!

Comment: This indeed worked perfectly for me. I find it VERY odd that apple uses java which they're depreciating to upload native code applications... and on top of that that the updates that they still distribute (though I know they don't make) break their developer functionality...

Comment: Where exactly are these commands supposed to be executed FROM? I know terminal.  But you're creating symlinks.  Presumably they need to reside somewhere, right?

Comment: Nevermind.  OSX seems to put it in the right place no matter what.  But you do need to check whether your system is using 1.5 or 1.5.0 when creating the symlink.

Comment: Update for everyone:

Installing Java for OS X 2012-002 fixes this issue, so just run Software Update.

Comment: Wow thanks! This is so great, I was pulling my hair out (almost)

Comment: When I saw this answer I thought "No way that will work for me because I'm not using Java anywhere," but the problem is with the Application Loader, so creating those symlinks worked.

Comment: I had the java 7 update installed (not apple released) so I went to the apple java preference and set the order so that apples java was first. Then restarted xCode this fixed it for me.

Comment: Had this exact same problem but these lines in the Terminal didn't do anything for me. FINALLY found something that worked for me at [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941342/java-2012-006-update-broke-xcode-uploading)  here were the lines that worked: cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo mv Current Current.bak
sudo mv CurrentJDK CurrentJDK.bak

Comment: Thanks everyone, but am I the only one wondering WHY IS XCODE DEPENDENT ON JAVA?

Comment: Hello, I have been getting same issue since two days,after using this answer, I am running java 1.6.0_65 in Maverics 10.9.3, so Where the problem ! Still getting the same issue!

Comment: Thanks, it saved lots of my time.

Answer (score 16):

I was having this problem this week, and installed the Java for OS X Lion 2012-002 update, and the problem cleared up. Resetting disk permissions had no effect.

Comment: We just ran into this issue using Xcode 4.3.2 on April 11, 2012, and this solution fixed it!  Thank you!

Comment: Same here - Xcode 4.3.2, April 11 2012. Ran Software Update and rebooted for good measure. Submission worked.

Comment: I am using xcode 5.1.1 and Mavericks-10.9.3 but getting same error though my Java version according to above answers is 1.6.0_65! Please help

Answer (score 15):

I had also a JavaVM / JRE issue. I have installed the JDK 7 preview from Oracle and that mixed up the upload process which told me the known "An error occurred uploading to the iTunes Store".

A quick check of `/var/log/system.log` (e.g. using tail in a terminal: `tail -n 100 /var/log/system.log`) brought up the following error message:

> Java 1.5, 1.6, or 1.7 is required. Currently, java is the default java version. Please upgrade.

I had installed the MacOS Preview of JDK 7 directly from Oracle. To fix this issue, simply launch the Java Settings app in Utilities and uncheck JDK 7 from Oracle. Of course you should have an alternate JRE from Apple. See the screenshot how my configuration looks. The upload works for me now.

The odd thing is that the Oracle JDK isn't recognized as Java 1.7 by Apple. This seems like a bug.

[image: Screenshot of my settings (sorry in German only, but you should get the clue)]

**UPDATE:**
The GUI tool was removed from MacOS. Now, the only solution I know of is to remove the JDK 1.7 folder manually. See the [JDK 7 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html#uninstall) how to do this:

> Navigate to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and remove the directory whose name matches the following format:
>
> `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<major>.<minor>.<macro[_update]>.jdk`
>
> For example, to uninstall 7u6:
>
> `% rm -rf jdk1.7.0_06.jdk`

Comment: This happened to me too after installing Xcode 4.5 DP4. Deactivating Java 1.7 did it. Thank you.

Comment: Does anyone know what happened to this? Worked great for me once but I think Apple might have done away with the tool.

Comment: Yes I noticed that too. So now the right solution is to uninstall JDK 7 manually. You have to remove the jdk1.7.xxxx directory in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines. You need root rights to do this.

Answer (score 15):

This just happened again.
For OSX 10.8.2 users (does not have Java preference), the only way to fix this is to uninstall oracle jdk.

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
sudo rm -rf jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/
```

Comment: This is what worked for me (except, instead of deleting the `.jdk` file, I moved it.

Comment: Here as well, I think it's the most accurate one now, also just moved the .jdk file and after submitting moved it back to its original place.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, I know - but for anyone still having this problem - Look in your /var/log/system.log log file. In my case the problem was that the iTMSTransporter script (used by the Organizer when uploading the file) used 'awk', and I had to replace it with '/usr/bin/awk'.

Completely solved my problem.

Y.

Comment: This fixed my problem as well... Thanks for the mentions of using the Console, which pointed the error out very explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this is useful for anyone else - for me it was that the Java JRE was not up-to-date.  I checked the console and Application Loader was complaining

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today after installing latest XCode.

I fixed it by running software update and installing latest Java Update.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing as Hernan, but even with application loader 1.3 I wasn't able to upload.

I noticed that this has happened after installing OSx Lion and upgrading XCode to 4.1!

I followed Joe's tip and I found out that JAVA wasn't even installed.

Follow this blog entry:

[Unable to Upload App to App Store](http://www.it-archives.com/Articles_iOS/UnabletoUploadtotheAppStoreafterinstallingOSxLionAndNewXcode41.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

My mbp now run Xcode4.2(4D199) on Lion, I installed the latest java for Lion. And finally I sovled this issue.

Many guys said, he can used the old Application Loader app to upload the apps. so I guess the problem is the latest Application Loader app(2.4.1 (190)), and the fact told me I am right

Okie, in short words:
Here is the solution:

1.I hope you guys do not delete the old Xcode(4.1). We Should pick up the old version Application Loader app.

```
cd <Install Xcode app>/Contents/Resources/Packages
cp ApplicationLoader.pkg ~/Desktop/
```

Now, you get the ApplicationLoader package.

2.Install the old one.
Tips: you can remove the latest Application Loader app in path: `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/` or just remane it.

That's All.

Hope this way can help you and enjoy the new Xcode4.2. Also hope apple developer can saw this problem and test the latest Application Loader app more.

Answer (score 0):

No Problems submitting to AppStore on April 1st. Issue occured on April 9th. Installing the Java for OS X Lion 2012-002 update via Mac-OS software updater and rebooting the machine fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just update to the latest JAVA at your Mac Software Update.

Comment: This was flagged as not an answer. While it could be improved or expanded a bit with an explanation, flagging it as NAA doesn't seem appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps to resolve this issue:

To start with I had installed Oracles Java 1.7 JDK, which was really messing things up.

Went to Finder>Applications and entered in Search box - JavaAppletPlugin.plugin

Right clicked and removed to trash.

A check in Terminal for Java version still showed Java 1.7

my-imac:~ my$ java -version

java version "1.7.0_07"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)

1. Finder>Library>Java>JavaVirtualMachines showed the 1.7 SDK (make note of exact name of the Directory name)

Just in case anything went wrong I copied the 1.7 SDK folder to my desktop before doing the next item

2. In terminal type

cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

3. You should now be in that directory

sudo rm -rf jdk1.7.0_06.jdk  (or whatever the exact name of the directory is in step 1.)

You may have to enter your administrator password

The directory should now be deleted and you can verify in Terminal by

java -version

Mine now showed "Java 1.6_xxx"

Went into Xcode Organizer and distributed my app to the iTunes store without a problem. Whoo,hoo!