# Xcode: an error occurred uploading to the itunes store

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, submit, itunes

Hey in trying to submit my app to iTunes.
It passes the validation, but when i submit it's showing an error:

```
an error occurred uploading to the iTunes store
```

[image]

What can i do?

Comment: This is not a programming question, and so unfortunately it's not really appropriate for Stack Overflow. You'll probably have better luck at http://devforums.apple.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can try:

First, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10021537/535632

Second, try using the Application Loader instead of XCode to submit the app