# Xcode 4.5 iOS 6 error uploading to itunes

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, xcode4.5, uploading

I have recently upgraded to XCode 4.5 and have been trying to release a new version of my app.  I went to the itunes connect portal and prepared it for upload.  I changed the version numbers in my bundle.  Now I archive it, and validate it.  No problems here.

The problem is when I try to distribute it I get this error
[image: An error occured uploading to the itunes store]

Before you rip this question appart, I have already tried these fixes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783481/an-error-occurred-uploading-to-the-itunes-store), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022981/an-error-occurred-uploading-to-the-itunes-store), and [by using the application loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045861/xcode-an-error-occurred-uploading-to-the-itunes-store)

I am out of ideas.  I really need to get this update out and I have no idea why I am getting this error.  If anyone else has had this problem, especially with xcode 4.5 (which seems to have started this problem in the first place) please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I finally solved my problem.  It is Java related as many of the other answers suggest, however their solutions didn't work for me.  I got some help from this [Apple Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4451649?start=0&tstart=0)

That solution still did not work for me though, so I did a slight workaround by just moving the virtual machine file. You could always move it back when you're done.

```
sudo mv -f /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7*jdk ~
```

You can confirm that this worked by checking the current java version

```
java -version
```

Which should give you 1.6.x.  This should fix the problem. Also note I still used Application Loader 2.7 to do this (Although I bet it would have worked either way).

Answer (score 1):

How long have you had this problem for?

In this case, it's probably due to [iTunes Connect scheduled maintenance](https://www.google.com/search?q=itunes+connect+scheduled+maintenance).

Comment: Just started today as far as I can tell.  I did get an email from apple saying they were doing maintenance yesterday, but its possible it is carrying over.  I will try again tomorrow and let you know, I hope that is it

Comment: Update: I have just attempted to try again today, still no luck.  I doubt this has anything to do with the maintenence