# An error occurred uploading to the iTunes Store from Application Loader

Tags: java, ios, xcode, application-loader

I'm over 12 hours in a row trying to figure the problem I have been trying to upload my IOS binary to itunes connect using Application Loader:

[image]

I have searched a lot, I found that seems it is helping most of people with the same issue: 
[image]

[StackOverlow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783481/an-error-occurred-uploading-to-the-itunes-store)

But that just doesn't work! I run java -version on console and it still says 1.7

I just can't find Java Preferences in order to switch the Java JMs, I am in panic and I just don't know what else to do.

Comment: Probably related to your firewall setting.  I needed to ease up my firewall settings when I was having some difficulty uploading recently.

Comment: [Here is my post please check it. That will resolve this issue 100% !!!!!][1]


  [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783481/an-error-occurred-uploading-to-the-itunes-store/17411430#17411430

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it, this linked helped me out:

[Link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4451649?start=0&tstart=0)

I hope it can save some time from someone with the same issue...