# An Error occurred uploading to the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, uploading

I could upload an app to App Store. It said successfully uploaded. However, 3 hour passed and I still can't get the reply e-mail from Apple. Therefore, I'm trying to upload it again (with new version 1.1) but I'm getting "an error occurred uploading to the App Store" error in both Application Loader and Xcode. I view this post [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783481/an-error-occurred-uploading-to-the-itunes-store/10021537#10021537). I even don't have any java version in my Mac. Therefore, none of solutions work for me.

I'm getting this error

> [2017-05-18 20:09:58 EEST]   INFO: Transporter is skipping bundle update check: Already checked recently.
>   An error occurred while trying to start transporter. Exception's name: java.lang.NullPointerException, Exception's message: Specified service reference cannot be null.

Comment: Is the build showing up in iTunes Connect > Activity > Processing? How about installing Java on your Mac?

Comment: I tried in different Mac and It worked now It is seen. But Still can't do that in my Mac.

Comment: As mentioned, did you try to un-install/re-install/install Java?

Comment: I haven't got any JAVA but I install java to see If problem will fix but nothing changed.